# c++ non-POD warning for passing a string?

Tags: c++, string, warnings, printf

```
void displayinfo(string &filename)
{
printf("%s% 38s\n", "Filename:", filename);
...
```

Warning: A non-POD object of type "std::string " passed as a variable argument to function "std::printf(const char*, ...)".

There is nothing online explaining what that warning means.

How would I get the printf to write this (assuming filename = test.txt):

Filename: (right justify filename) test.txt

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The explanation is quite simple: only PODs (Plain Old Data structures) can be passed as an argument to a variadic function (not a variadic function *template* though, just a simple variadic function using the ellipses).

`std::string` is not a POD, but you can do:

```
printf("%s% 38s\n", "Filename:", filename.c_str());
//                                       ^^^^^^^^
```

The [`c_str()` member function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) returns a `const char*` to the encapsulated C string.

Answer (score 4):

[`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), when used with the `%s` format specifier, requires a pointer to char. You can get that from an `std::string` via the `c_str()` method:

```
printf("%s% 38s\n", "Filename:", filename.c_str());
```

As an aside, note that if you don't intend to modify or copy the input string, you should pass by `const` reference:

```
void displayinfo(const string& filename) { .... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I seriously doubt the net would be silent. Maybe you looked at wrong places or used nad keyworrs.

The basic rule is simple, passing non-POD as ... argument is undefined behavior. Don't do it unless your implementation defined some behavior and it matches your task.

And particularly for printf family, there the format string requires specific types to pass, you broke that even if passing POD worked.